# Grabbing selected <button>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of buttons:

```
<button id="hdfs-test" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HDFS</button>
<button id="hive-test" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HIVE</button>
<button id="hdfs-hive-test" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">BOTH</button>
```

I gather them with:

```
var testType = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

I was wondering how I can pick out the selected one, if any, and run some logic if one of the three buttons is selected and run other logic if NONE are selected.

Comment: what do you mean with selected?

Comment: @baao clicked on and highlighted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an EventListener on click for each button and run a function for `this`:

```
for (var i = 0; i<testType.length; i++) {
testType.addEventListener('click',function() {
  console.log(this.id);
  /* run code for every button */
   if (this.id == 'hive-test') {
      /* run code only for button with id hive-test */
   }
  });
 }
```